# GYP variable based on build configuration

Tags: node-gyp, gyp

Is it possible to define a GYP variable whose value depends on the choice of build configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Just use variable `$(BUILDTYPE)` or `$(ConfigurationName)`.

Comment: Better use `<(CONFIGURATION_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's impossible according to [this](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/InputFormatReference#Processing_Order) wiki page:

> - Perform “early” or “pre” variable expansion and conditional evaluation.
> - ...
> - Merge target settings into configurations as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's possible if you mean distinctions between 'Debug' and 'Release' by the 'build configuration'. Try to add the following in your *.gyp file:

```
...
'configurations': {
    'Debug': {
        'variables': {
            'some_variable%' : 'debug_value',
    },
    'Release': {
        'variables': {
            'some_variable%' : 'release_value',
        },
    },
}
...
```

Links with some more examples: [gyp - how to specify link library flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979860/gyp-how-to-specify-link-library-flavor/14058852#14058852); http://n8.io/converting-a-c-library-to-gyp/

Comment: The article can be found at GitHub: https://github.com/TooTallNate/n8.io/blob/master/articles/converting-a-c-library-to-gyp.markdown

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work. Attempting to use the variable in 'libraries', and just get `Undefined variable some_variable in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp`.